python3.12 -m pip setuptools gets No module named 'distutils'
I added python3.12 to Ubuntu, and python3 --version is python3.12 and it works.
I want to install jupyter but it gets No module named 'distutils'
I understand distutils was deprecated in 3.12, but setuptools has it's own version.
However, python3.12 -m pip setuptools gets No module named 'distutils'

You should not change the default python3 version IF you wish the Ubuntu tools that came with your system to work correctly (esp. on Desktop systems). You've not provided any product or release details (ie. is this a Server? Core? or Desktop? system, and what release) as the only release where python3 is 12 by default is currently still in alpha and thus off-topic on this site.

Does this answer your question? Why is apt so dependent on individual Python versions?

I'm running Mint 21.3. I understand the problem with changing the default python3 version, so I resolved that by creating an alias for python=python3.12. Now python3 -V is 3.10 (OS installed) and python -V is 3.12. That post about apt didn't solve my problem about installing jupyter, but this command worked: pip install -U pip setuptools wheel. Then I was able to pip install jupyterlab.

Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu are on-topic here, refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Linux Mint forum. (One advantage of Ubuntu is it's many support options, you opted for Linux Mint so take advantage of its support options, or SE Unix & Linux found in the on-topic link)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76691103/13086128
